# Onhover change effect in css

Tags: html, css

I have created box with image, link, title and some values. I want to create effect on mouse over/hover.

Here I added the class to do:

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/s5q9w/13/)

but it does not create effect. What's wrong.

Is this wrong way to do this?

```
.c1:hover{

.item .moreBtn{position: relative;font-size: 14px;margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 32px;}  

.item .pillBtn{-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;background:#7CDD97;padding: 10.5px 40px 8.0px 40px;color: #FFF;font-weight: bold;font-size: 20px;text-decoration: none;}

    .item h6 {margin-top: 18px;}

    .item{background:#F3F3F3;height: 70px;-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;}

}
```

Comment: you can't nest css, unless you use sass/less/scss. you have to `c1:hover .item .moreBtn {}`

Comment: Even in scss, you have to reference parent with &. `.item` inside `.item` won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can't nest styles with pure CSS. You can do that with a pre-processor like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)

Your *pure* CSS could look something like:

```
.item:hover .moreBtn {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 32px;
}
.item:hover .pillBtn {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    background:#7CDD97;
    padding: 10.5px 40px 8.0px 40px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.item:hover {
    background:#F3F3F3;
    height: 70px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

So long as `.moreBtn` and `.pillBtn` are descendants of `.item`

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/s5q9w/17/)

Comment: thanks, there is 8 minutes left to select as correct answer. Actually I want maximized version of box and `whatmore ..` highlighted when user takes mouse over entire box. I appreciate your help if you can do something attractive in that direction.

Comment: The styles are up to you, I don't know what your desired result is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested CSS styles in plain CSS.

You need to use pseudo-class `:hover` like this:

```
.item:hover .moreBtn { ... }     
.item:hover .pillBtn { ... }
.item:hover { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Transition:
Transition effect on the width property, duration: 2 seconds:

```
.item{
transition:width 2s;
}
```

&

```
.item:hover{
height:200px;
background-color:red;
}
```